# Variable + text within post(construct) within loop

Tags: php

In a quiz project want the

```
if(isset($_POST['choicei']))
```

to be executed after every radio button is selected, but I want it to get incremented with the for loop for variable `i`. How to use it? I tried:

```
if(isset($_POST['choice.$i.']))
```

Which did not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your PHP variable inside single quotes which PHP behaves as characters.

Put your variable inside double quotes.

`if(isset($_POST["choice$i"]))` or `if(isset($_POST["choice" . $i]))`